# How to remove the values stored in hash map from shared preference android

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I have the list of hash map values and stored in shared preference. How to remove the hash map value from shared preference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show some code what have to done up till now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has too few details. Generally you should get your values from shared preferences, edit this value and commit it using the same key. In other way you can use other value to store it to the shared prefferences overriding existing key.